# Implementing/Simulating TOR(The Onion Router) with ns2.

Tags: network-programming, simulation, simulator, ns2, tor

I am trying to simulate a TOR(The Onion Router) network
Since i'm new to ns2 I would like to know whether it is possible to actually simulate it using this tool.
The things that I require for my project:

1.Layers of encryption and decryption:
    After the packet moves from one node to another it should be possible for that node to decrypt/encrypt the packet that arrives to find the address of the next node the packet is to be forwarded to.

2.A server node that controls all the other nodes in the network and also has routing tables and calculates paths for a transfer of data.

3.Whenever a new node is added to the network the node should be processed by the server node.

4.Have our own encryption/decryption code.

Would like to know if all this is possible using ns2.
If not any alternative approach is appreciated.
Thank you guys.!

Answer (score 1):

tor has a built-in test network function. it's not well documented yet, but there are several possible entries in torrc that can set up a test network. what little info that does exist can be found at https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en